# Statistical test to prove correlation between different independent variables and dependent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Having information about different variables like age group, intensity of game playing, game violence, social intelligence, and parent-child communication of hundreds of children, how could the hypothesis, that age, social intelligence, and parent-child communication moderate the association between digital game playing and aggression, be statistically proven?

Comment: Proving something means establishing it with absolute certainty, which can't be done in real-world data analysis. The most you can do is find evidence for something, or show that it is highly probable, or find evidence against alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

let X =digital game, Y=aggression,

if you omit the moderators, it would be Y~X

if you want to see the moderation effect of age,

you simply put age * X in the regression model,

which would be Y ~ X + age + (age - mean.age) * ( X - mean.X)

(mean.age is the mean of age, mean.x is the mean of X,

if you simply put age * X, you would get high correlation between predictors and

the S.E. of coefficients would be big)